# Showing loading message when loading internal pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using jQuery Mobile for a PhoneGap app. When I try to load an internal page like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#loginPage', { transition: "none"} );
```

The app waits for a fews moments then the page changes to the login page. Is it possible to show the loading message while the page is being loaded? I know changePage has a showLoadingMsg option but that only works for external pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` on `pagebeforecreate` or `pagebeforeshow` event (depending on your case) and then `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` on `pageshow` event. Something like this:

```
$(document).on(
   'pageshow',
   '#loginPage'
   function()
   {
      $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
   }
);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it feels like the changePage function destroys any loading messages. If I put $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); just before changePage, or bind that to pagebeforecreate and pagebeforeshow, and delete all hidePageLoadingMsg() from the page, it still doesn't show... it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that there is a delay of about half a second after something is pressed and the javascript being called, guess there's no way around that...

Comment: So the whole problem was really my above comment, the actual page loading is instant. Just found that the delay mentioned above can be removed by instead of binding to click events for buttons you bind to vclick. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-remove-the-300ms-delay-when-clicking-on-a-link-in-jquery-mobile